# Is Sql server express edition 2014 expire?

Tags: sql

I am using SqlServer Express edition 2014 for office purpose. I'm using it since 6 months, but I couldn't found any expiry alert. Could you please suggest I can use it for permanently or will it be expired?

Please let us know how to know expiry date. Thanks.

Comment: express is free,but has some limitations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express edition is free.
Just for fun, run this query :

```
SELECT  create_date AS 'SQL Server Installed Date',
        Expiry_date AS 'SQL Server Expiry Date',
    DATEDIFF(dd,create_date, GETDATE()) 'No_of_Days_Used',
    ABS(DATEDIFF(dd,expiry_date,GETDATE())) 'No_Of_Days_Left'
FROM
(SELECT sp.create_date,
        DATEADD(dd, 180, sp.create_date) AS Expiry_date
 FROM   sys.server_principals sp
 WHERE  sp.name = 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM') as exp_date_tbs
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL server express edition is a free version that does not expire. What might expire and need to be updated or switch to other versions such as Express is the Enterprise Evaluation Edition.